# \newlist vs. \newenvironment for defining an individual list style

Tags: environments, enumitem

as far as I know, there are two ways of defining an individual list style:

1) Use the `enumitem` package and the `\newlist` and `\setlist` commands

2) Define an individual environment like the following example:

```
\newenvironment{exampleEnumeration}
{\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, itemsep=2pt, parsep=0pt]}
{\end{enumerate}}
```

Now my question is: which way should I prefer? Is it only a difference in convenience or are there more imporant aspects I'm not aware of? Thank you!

Comment: With `newlist` you can easily add extra options on individual instances.

Comment: also with `\newlist` you can use `\setlist[mylist]{...}` to globally configure `mylist`. So `\newlist` is preferable.

Comment: It depends. If `enumitem` is incompatible with the class or packages you are using, that option is ruled out. This won't happen with `\newenvironment` because that's a standard LaTeX command. However, the way you've used `\newenvironment` depends on `enumitem` anyway so I cannot see any point in using it in that case. If you are loading `enumitem` anyhow, why not use its facilities in the form of `\newlist` etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\newlist` is primarily for defining new sets of enumerated/itemized lists. For instance

```
\newlist{exampleEnumeration}
\setlist[exampleEnumeration]{leftmargin=*, itemsep=2pt, parsep=0pt}
```

would be illegal, because you *must* specify `label` (and optionally `ref`). If you don't specify the level, the same label will be used at all levels. So you should type, say,

```
\newlist{exampleEnumeration}
\setlist[exampleEnumeration,1]{leftmargin=*, itemsep=2pt, parsep=0pt, label=\arabic*.}
\setlist[exampleEnumeration,2]{leftmargin=*, itemsep=2pt, parsep=0pt, label=(\alph*)}
```

and so on.

With `\newenvironment` the label corresponding to the current nesting level will be used.

A better definition would be

```
\newenvironment{exampleEnumeration}[1][]
  {\enumerate[leftmargin=*, itemsep=2pt, parsep=0pt, #1]}
  {\endenumerate}
```

so that you can pass more options to `exampleEnumeration`; moreover, using `\enumerate` and `\endenumerate` you would get more meaningful error messages when the nesting is wrong.