# how to create book with multiple exam question papers in chapters?

Tags: document-classes, exam, books

I want to bundle together multiple exam question papers in the form of a bound book to be handed out as practice problems. The exam question papers are mainly objective MCQs. Each chapter will have initial description (text, figures, and diagrams) followed by a series of multiple choice questions.
I use the `exam class` to generate MCQ exams as shown in the code below.
How to combine this with book templates or or other class to accomplish what I wish to do?

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\question
 [A]
question 1 \\
\begin{oneparchoices}
 \choice  option 1
 \choice  option 2
 \choice  option 3
 \choice  option 4
\end{oneparchoices}


\question
 [B]
question 2 \\
\begin{oneparchoices}
 \choice  option 1
 \choice  option 2
 \choice  option 3
 \choice  option 4
\end{oneparchoices}

\question
 [A]
question 3 \\
\begin{oneparchoices}
 \choice  option 1
 \choice  option 2
 \choice  option 3
 \choice  option 4
\end{oneparchoices}

\question
 [D]
question 4 \\
\begin{oneparchoices}
 \choice  option 1
 \choice  option 2
 \choice  option 3
 \choice  option 4
\end{oneparchoices}


\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can compound your chapter introductions with a book class and insert your previously formatted exams with [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) help.

Comment: thanks, but it seems pdfpages is not working, may be because the question paper pdf contains many images. I will see if it works by changing few things.

Comment: I guess, the problem is from the geometry package; it seems pdfpages doesn't go well with geometry package.

Comment: also the limitation of pdfpages that it always inserts at new page; it is not desired in this case; even if there is a lot of space on the current page, the pdfpages will still insert on new page :(

Comment: I understood that you wanted to include your exams, but looks like you only want to include questions from exams. How would you like to proceed? Do you only want to `\include{exam.tex}`? Then you need some way of forgetting exam preamble. Can you copy and paste questions into your new book? You need to define a `question` environment in your book preamble.

Comment: okay, can you give an example of how to define a minimal `question`  environment that allows me to write MCQs with questions numbered from given `start` counter to `end` counter. I will accept that as answer; sorry cannot upvote your comment; don't have that permission yet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that OP only wants to include some multiple choice questions typed like in `exam` class, i.e., a `questions` environment similar to `enumerate` but with `\question[points]` command instead of `\item`; and a multiple choice environment (`oneparchoices`) which is similar to an inline enumerate with `\choice` instead of `\item`.

Both environments can be build with [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package. It provides configurable lists and also configurable inline lists. Therefore with some help from `enumitem` documentation, and from [\newlist vs. \newenvironment for defining an individual list style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188150/1952) and [Creating a list style with enumitem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236668/1952), next can be done

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}

%Idea from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236668/1952
\DeclareDocumentCommand\question{o}{%
    \item\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{(#1 points)}}

\newenvironment{questions}[1][]{\enumerate[,#1]}{\endenumerate}

\newlist{oneparchoices}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[oneparchoices,1]{label=\Alph*., itemjoin={{\quad}}}

\newcommand{\choice}{\item}

\begin{document}

Some questions to start with
\begin{questions}[start=4] %<--- start option fixes number for first question
\question[A] question 1 \\
\begin{oneparchoices}
 \choice  option 1
 \choice  option 2
 \choice  option 3
 \choice  option 4
\end{oneparchoices}

\question[B] question 2  \\
\begin{oneparchoices}
 \choice  option 1
 \choice  option 2
 \choice  option 3
 \choice  option 4
\end{oneparchoices}

\question question \label{q}\ref{q} without points
\end{questions}
and, now, two more
\begin{questions}[resume] %<--- resume option follows counting from last time 

\question[A] question 1 \\
\begin{oneparchoices}
 \choice  option 1
 \choice  option 2
 \choice  option 3
 \choice  option 4
\end{oneparchoices}

\question[B] question 2  \\
\begin{oneparchoices}
 \choice  option 1
 \choice  option 2
 \choice  option 3
 \choice  option 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]